# How can I boost query terms in PostgreSQL full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, ranking

Is it possible to give weights or boost query terms in PostgresSQL full text search?

For example, while searching using the keywords "vehicle", "bus" ... it would rank higher rows with "vehicle" but lower to "bus".

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `setweight` function on the `tsvector` to assign a specific weight to certain elements of the vector:

```
setweight(to_tsvector('english', '...'), 'A', '{vehicl}')
```

Then the `ts_rank` function will count occurrences of `vehicle` higher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that. But I am working on query expansion and I was looking for a way to consider synonyms,hyponyms or hypernyms. So, my query would look like "SynonymTerm1"*1 | "HypernymTerm2"*0.5 | "HyponymTerm" * 0.5 or similar. The example is just a generic one but at the query level so that synonym and the word itself would have the same weight while the weight of the other forms will be lowered. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Then you probably need a [synonym dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is combining multiple query ranks into one. It covers other relaxation techniques than just per term relaxation/boosting - notice the simple dictionary in my example. It also works on SaaS versions of PostgreSQL where one can't mess around with custom extensions / dictionaries.

> The built-in ranking functions are only examples. You can write your own ranking functions and/or **combine their results with additional factors to fit your specific needs.**
>
> [PostgreSQL docs - Controlling Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING)

```
CREATE TABLE animal
(
    name text
);

insert into animal
values ('cat-dog'),
       ('cat dog'),
       ('dog-cat'),
       ('dog cat'),
       ('cats and dogs'),
       ('dogs and cats'),
       ('cat'),
       ('dog');

create index animal_fulltext_idx on animal using gist (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')));

SELECT name,
       to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'cats & dogs') as original_query_matches,
       ts_rank(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('english', 'cats & dogs')) as original_query_rank,
       to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'cats & dogs') as strict_query_matches,
       ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('simple', 'cats & dogs')) * 1.05 as strict_query_rank,
       to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'cats <2> dogs') as extra_strict_query_matches,
       ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('simple', 'cats <2> dogs')) * 1.15 as extra_strict_query_rank,
       to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'cats | dogs') as relaxed_query_matches,
       ts_rank(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('english', 'cats | dogs')) * 0.95 as relaxed_query_rank,
       greatest(
               CASE
                   WHEN to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'cats & dogs')
                       THEN ts_rank(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('english', 'cats & dogs'))
                   ELSE 0 END,
               CASE
                   WHEN to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'cats & dogs')
                       THEN ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('simple', 'cats & dogs')) * 1.05
                   ELSE 0 END,
               CASE
                   WHEN to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'cats <2> dogs')
                       THEN ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('simple', 'cats <2> dogs')) * 1.15
                   ELSE 0 END,
               CASE
                   WHEN to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'cats | dogs')
                       THEN ts_rank(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')), to_tsquery('english', 'cats | dogs')) * 0.95
                   ELSE 0 END
           ) as greatest_rank
FROM animal
where to_tsvector('english', coalesce(name, '')) @@ (to_tsquery('english', 'cats & dogs') || to_tsquery('english', 'cats <-> dogs') || to_tsquery('english', 'cats | dogs'))
order by greatest_rank desc;
```

- ts_rank computes non-zero number even if query doesn't "match", that is
  why the case expressions are present.
- The result of "match" query in
  where should be a super-set for results of all "match" queries in the
  ranking part of the query.
- Beware the "coalesce" function - if you use it in the query but not in the index then the index will not be used.
- to_tsvector in index definition must have a config specified to make it immutable.
- Indexed ts_vector config and config for ts_vector used with @@ must be the same for index to be used.
- If you use setweight with the @@ operator but not in the index then the index will not be used.

Tested on PostgreSQL 12.2.

(If anyone knows how to achieve the same result with simpler/faster query I would 
 love to hear about it.)